# Firebase Authentication from Google App Script?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add firebase authentication to my google doc add on. My goal is to have a sidebar that displays data from my database after authentication. I get the most confused by other answers because I'm unsure about what goes in the html file verse what goes in the google app script file. I know I'm supposed to create a token but after I copy and paste that code from the tutorial I get lost.

Groups/Answers that were partly helpful:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/-RKpHaMPTYQ

[Google Authentication with Google Spread Sheet via App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949432/google-authentication-with-google-spread-sheet-via-app-script)

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/using-secured-client-authentication-for-real-time-read-and-write-calls

app.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.3/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="databaseDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
/**
 * Creates a menu entry in the Google Docs UI when the document is opened.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('app')
      .setTitle('Sow Google Docs');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function makeToken(){ 

  var firebaseUrl = "https://example.firebaseio.com/"; 
  var secret = "EXAMPLEKEYYEKELPMAXE"; 
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret); 
  var token = base.createAuthToken(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); 
  return token; 

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i dont see how you are including the firebase library. if you Google it there is a working example from apps script.

Comment: I do have the [firebase library](https://script.google.com/macros/library/versions/d/1hguuh4Zx72XVC1Zldm_vTtcUUKUA6iBUOoGnJUWLfqDWx5WlOJHqYkrt) if that's what you're referring to. All the examples I found didn't outline what goes in what file or were depreciated. Could you please point me to one?

Comment: Ok, sorry initially I thought you wanted to call firebase from .gs (ive done that) but in your case its a "regular" use of firebase from the frontend and you should do everything on the frontend. you might want to pass the user email address to the frontend to make it easier to start the auth flow from there with that email address.

Comment: How would I call firebase from .gs? I think that would be better.

Comment: no, you dont want that. but google a little, there is a library for it.

Comment: For future users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604004/firebase-service-account-to-generate-authentication-token-for-client-side-use-wi/54614597#54614597. I had issues with Firebase in Apps Script but eventually figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any custom firebase library for apps script, use the [Official Firebase Inline Javascript Libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) to achieve your objectives. If you run into problems ask your questions here (but do not be clueless), people will help.